# unity: rope swing 3d character jump on start

Tags: c#, swing, unity-game-engine

I try to create a rope-swinging (penudulum like, around virtual point) mechanic in unity. But on first frame of swing my character suddenly jump far back and down and only then continue moving forward and down pendulum like.

```
void InitSwing(){
    lineLenght = (transform.position - virtualLinePoint).sqrMagnitude;}

    public void SwingLocomotion()
    {
        Vector3 testPos = transform.position + jMotor.moveDirection *Time.deltaTime;
        float newLenght = (testPos - virtualLinePoint).sqrMagnitude;
        if (newLenght != lineLenght)
        {
            testPos = virtualLinePoint + (testPos - virtualLinePoint).normalized * lineLenght;

        }
        transform.position = testPos;
```

Answer (score 0):

Could it be due to Time.deltaTime being 0 on the first frame? Therefore the line `jMotor.moveDirection *Time.deltaTime` would return 0 and testPos would equal `transform.position + 0`

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. I mean first frame of jump, not game itself.